How to set up view access in AWS managed grafana via terraform
I am using AWS managed grafana and I configured it with SAML via terraform. Now in saml config there are two parameters admin_role_values and editor_role_values, but I am not getting anything on the view. I need help to understand how can I configure AWS managed grafana for view access.
Here's what I got:
resource "aws_grafana_workspace_saml_configuration" "saml" {
  editor_role_values = ["Developer"]
  idp_metadata_url   = var.idp_metadata_url
  workspace_id       = aws_grafana_workspace.grafana.id
  admin_role_values =  ["Admins"]
  email_assertion         = "mail"
  login_assertion         = "mail"
  login_validity_duration = 144
  name_assertion          = "displayName"
  role_assertion          = "roles"
} 

I was expecting something with view as well, but not finding anything on how can I get it done via terraform.

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.
